# db2 connection with jsp

Tags: jsp, db2

```
String userid = request.getParameter("uname");    
String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver").newInstance();
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/TEST","root","atul");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs;
rs = st.executeQuery("select * from members where uname='" + userid + "' and pass='" + pwd"'");         
if (rs.next()) {
    session.setAttribute("userid", userid);
    //out.println("welcome " + userid);
    //out.println("<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>");
    response.sendRedirect("success.jsp");
} else {
    out.println("Invalid password <a href='index.jsp'>try again</a>");
}
%>
```

I have installed db2 v9.7 and use jdbc connector v9.7fp5_jdbc_sqlj for db2 in directory web-inf/lib (db2jcc.jar and db2jcc.jar) of ecilpse and create database test in db2 with username :root ans password :atul. I've db2 installed in my system. I've restarted tomcat many times, in fact restarted my pc many times, searched the google and found the above code only. Error is

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /login.jsp at line 18
type Exception report
message An exception occurred processing JSP page /login.jsp at line 18description. The
 server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request
 request.
```

stacktrace

```
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: wrap your code into a try-catch block and print the exception stacktrace, please

Comment: Wrap your scriptlet code in a `try-catch` block. In the `catch(Exception e)` block, add `e.printStackTrace();`. Then edit your question and copy the stacktrace message here.

Comment: There is an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22388320/edit) option below the question content. Please select it and **add** the stacktrace below the current content. Do not post it in a comment.

Comment: Please post the whole stacktrace. In its current state, it doesn't give any hint about what the problem is.

Comment: above jsp code work with mysql  ,if i replace drivername and other required things but it didnt work with db2

Comment: problem solved ,by changing authority of user root